# Adding keyCode events to javascript Calculator

Tags: javascript, html, function, events, key

I'm having trouble getting this calculator to function properly when typing numbers as opposed to clicking the number buttons. I added some javascript that takes the key codes as an array and adds the correct number to my displayVal. It works at first but once an operator is pressed and the number is stored as 'pendingVal', the number '0' is added to the beginning of the numbers when typed and returns odd calculations for numbers over 10. If anyone sees the issue or has another work around for this that involves only JS, it would be much appreciated.

```js
var oneBtn = document.getElementById("btn1");
var twoBtn = document.getElementById("btn2");
var threeBtn = document.getElementById("btn3");
var fourBtn = document.getElementById("btn4");
var fiveBtn = document.getElementById("btn5");
var sixBtn = document.getElementById("btn6");
var sevenBtn = document.getElementById("btn7");
var eightBtn = document.getElementById("btn8");
var nineBtn = document.getElementById("btn9");
var zeroBtn = document.getElementById("btn0");

var decimalBtn = document.getElementById("btnDec");
var clearBtn = document.getElementById("btnClear");
var percentBtn = document.getElementById("btnPer");
var plusMinBtn = document.getElementById("btnPM");

var displayValElement = document.getElementById("output");

var calcNumBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("calcNum");
var calcOperators = document.getElementsByClassName("calcOp");

var displayVal = '0';
var pendingVal;
var evalStringArray = [];

var updateDisplayVal = (clickObj) => {
var btnText = clickObj.target.innerText;

  if (displayVal === '0')
    displayVal = '';

  displayVal += btnText;
  displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
}

var performOperation = (clickObj) => {
  var operator = clickObj.target.innerText;

  switch (operator) {
  case '+':
    pendingVal = displayVal;
    displayVal = '0';
    displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
    evalStringArray.push(pendingVal);
    evalStringArray.push('+');
    break;
  case '-':
    pendingVal = displayVal;
    displayVal = '0';
    displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
    evalStringArray.push(pendingVal);
    evalStringArray.push('-');
    break;
  case 'x':
    pendingVal = displayVal;
    displayVal = '0';
    displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
    evalStringArray.push(pendingVal);
    evalStringArray.push('*');
    break;
  case '÷':
    pendingVal = displayVal;
    displayVal = '0';
    displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
    evalStringArray.push(pendingVal);
    evalStringArray.push('/');
    break;
  case '=':
    evalStringArray.push(displayVal);
    var evaluation = eval(evalStringArray.join(' '));
    displayVal = evaluation + '';
    displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
    evalStringArray = [];
    break;
  default: 
    break;
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < calcNumBtns.length; i++) {
  calcNumBtns[i].addEventListener('click', updateDisplayVal, false);
}

for (let i = 0; i < calcOperators.length; i++) {
  calcOperators[i].addEventListener('click', performOperation, false);
}

// Added to remove initial 0 for displayVal when typing

var keys = [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57];

for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  if (keyCode = keys[i] && displayVal == '0') {
    displayVal = '';
  }
}

// Adds ability to type #'s to buttons

 function keyCodeOne (event) {
    if (event.which == 49 || event.keyCode == 49) {
        displayVal += 1;
        displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyCodeOne, false);

function keyCodeTwo (event) {
    if (event.which == 50 || event.keyCode == 50) {
        displayVal += '2';
        displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyCodeTwo, false);

function keyCodeThree (event) {
    if (event.which == 51 || event.keyCode == 51) {
        displayVal += '3';
        displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyCodeThree, false);

function keyCodeFour (event) {
    if (event.which == 52 || event.keyCode == 52) {
        displayVal += '4';
        displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyCodeFour, false);

function keyCodeFive (event) {
    if (event.which == 53 || event.keyCode == 53) {
        displayVal += '5';
        displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyCodeFive, false);

function keyCodeSix (event) {
    if (event.which == 54 || event.keyCode == 54) {
        displayVal += '6';
        displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyCodeSix, false);

function keyCodeSeven (event) {
    if (event.which == 55 || event.keyCode == 55) {
        displayVal += '7';
        displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyCodeSeven, false);

function keyCodeEight (event) {
    if (event.which == 56 || event.keyCode == 56) {
       displayVal += '8';
        displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyCodeEight, false);

function keyCodeNine (event) {
    if (event.which == 57 || event.keyCode == 57) {
        displayVal += '9';
        displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyCodeNine, false);

function keyCodeZero (event) {
    if (event.which == 48 || event.keyCode == 48) {

        displayVal += '0';
        displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyCodeZero, false);
```

```html
<section id="mainContainer">

  <div id="calcContainer">
  <form id="form" name="form">
    <div id="displayBox">
      <div id="output" class="textView">0</div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <table id="table" class="calcTable" cellspacing="10px">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><button id="btnClear" class="calcBtn tr1">AC</button></td>
      <td><button id="btnPM" class="calcBtn tr1">+/-</button></td>
      <td><button id="btnPer" class="calcBtn tr1">%</button></td>
      <td><button id="btnDiv" class="calcBtn calcOp tr2">&#247</button></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
      <td><button id="btn9" class="calcBtn calcNum">7</button></td>
      <td><button id="btn8" class="calcBtn calcNum">8</button></td>
      <td><button id="btn7" class="calcBtn calcNum">9</button></td>
      <td><button id="btnMul" class="calcBtn calcOp tr2">x</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button id="btn4" class="calcBtn calcNum">4</button></td>
      <td><button id="btn5" class="calcBtn calcNum">5</button></td>
      <td><button id="btn6" class="calcBtn calcNum">6</button></td>
      <td><button id="btnSub" class="calcBtn calcOp tr2">-</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button id="btn1" class="calcBtn calcNum">1</button></td>
      <td><button id="btn2" class="calcBtn calcNum">2</button></td>
      <td><button id="btn3" class="calcBtn calcNum">3</button></td>
      <td><button id="btnAdd" class="calcBtn calcOp tr2">+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><button id="btn0" class="calcBtn calcNum">0</button></td>
      <td><button id="btnDec" class="calcBtn">.</button></td>
      <td><button id="btnEq" class="calcBtn calcOp tr2">=</button></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, try to put a check for each button click to verify if first number is a 0 like this:

```
if(displayVal === '0') displayVal = '';
```

Look this example:

```js
var oneBtn = document.getElementById("btn1");
var twoBtn = document.getElementById("btn2");
var threeBtn = document.getElementById("btn3");
var fourBtn = document.getElementById("btn4");
var fiveBtn = document.getElementById("btn5");
var sixBtn = document.getElementById("btn6");
var sevenBtn = document.getElementById("btn7");
var eightBtn = document.getElementById("btn8");
var nineBtn = document.getElementById("btn9");
var zeroBtn = document.getElementById("btn0");

var decimalBtn = document.getElementById("btnDec");
var clearBtn = document.getElementById("btnClear");
var percentBtn = document.getElementById("btnPer");
var plusMinBtn = document.getElementById("btnPM");

var displayValElement = document.getElementById("output");

var calcNumBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("calcNum");
var calcOperators = document.getElementsByClassName("calcOp");

var displayVal = '0';
var pendingVal;
var evalStringArray = [];

var updateDisplayVal = (clickObj) => {
var btnText = clickObj.target.innerText;

  if (displayVal === '0')
    displayVal = '';

  displayVal += btnText;
  displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
}

var performOperation = (clickObj) => {
  var operator = clickObj.target.innerText;

  switch (operator) {
  case '+':
    pendingVal = displayVal;
    displayVal = '0';
    displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
    evalStringArray.push(pendingVal);
    evalStringArray.push('+');
    break;
  case '-':
    pendingVal = displayVal;
    displayVal = '0';
    displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
    evalStringArray.push(pendingVal);
    evalStringArray.push('-');
    break;
  case 'x':
    pendingVal = displayVal;
    displayVal = '0';
    displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
    evalStringArray.push(pendingVal);
    evalStringArray.push('*');
    break;
  case '÷':
    pendingVal = displayVal;
    displayVal = '0';
    displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
    evalStringArray.push(pendingVal);
    evalStringArray.push('/');
    break;
  case '=':
    evalStringArray.push(displayVal);
    var evaluation = eval(evalStringArray.join(' '));
    displayVal = evaluation + '';
    displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
    evalStringArray = [];
    break;
  default: 
    break;
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < calcNumBtns.length; i++) {
  calcNumBtns[i].addEventListener('click', updateDisplayVal, false);
}

for (let i = 0; i < calcOperators.length; i++) {
  calcOperators[i].addEventListener('click', performOperation, false);
}

// Added to remove initial 0 for displayVal when typing

var keys = [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57];

for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  if (keyCode = keys[i] && displayVal == '0') {
    displayVal = '';
  }
}

// Adds ability to type #'s to buttons

 function keyCodeOne (event) {
    if (event.which == 49 || event.keyCode == 49) {
        if(displayVal === '0') displayVal = '';
        displayVal += 1;
        displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyCodeOne, false);

function keyCodeTwo (event) {
    if (event.which == 50 || event.keyCode == 50) {
        if(displayVal === '0') displayVal = '';
        displayVal += '2';
        displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyCodeTwo, false);

function keyCodeThree (event) {
    if (event.which == 51 || event.keyCode == 51) {
        if(displayVal === '0') displayVal = '';
        displayVal += '3';
        displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyCodeThree, false);

function keyCodeFour (event) {
    if (event.which == 52 || event.keyCode == 52) {
        if(displayVal === '0') displayVal = '';
        displayVal += '4';
        displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyCodeFour, false);

function keyCodeFive (event) {
    if (event.which == 53 || event.keyCode == 53) {
        if(displayVal === '0') displayVal = '';
        displayVal += '5';
        displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyCodeFive, false);

function keyCodeSix (event) {
    if (event.which == 54 || event.keyCode == 54) {
        if(displayVal === '0') displayVal = '';
        displayVal += '6';
        displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyCodeSix, false);

function keyCodeSeven (event) {
    if (event.which == 55 || event.keyCode == 55) {
        if(displayVal === '0') displayVal = '';
        displayVal += '7';
        displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyCodeSeven, false);

function keyCodeEight (event) {
    if (event.which == 56 || event.keyCode == 56) {
       if(displayVal === '0') displayVal = '';
       displayVal += '8';
        displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyCodeEight, false);

function keyCodeNine (event) {
    if (event.which == 57 || event.keyCode == 57) {
        if(displayVal === '0') displayVal = '';
        displayVal += '9';
        displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyCodeNine, false);

function keyCodeZero (event) {
    if (event.which == 48 || event.keyCode == 48) {

        displayVal += '0';
        displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyCodeZero, false);
```

```html
<section id="mainContainer">

  <div id="calcContainer">
  <form id="form" name="form">
    <div id="displayBox">
      <div id="output" class="textView">0</div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <table id="table" class="calcTable" cellspacing="10px">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><button id="btnClear" class="calcBtn tr1">AC</button></td>
      <td><button id="btnPM" class="calcBtn tr1">+/-</button></td>
      <td><button id="btnPer" class="calcBtn tr1">%</button></td>
      <td><button id="btnDiv" class="calcBtn calcOp tr2">&#247</button></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
      <td><button id="btn9" class="calcBtn calcNum">7</button></td>
      <td><button id="btn8" class="calcBtn calcNum">8</button></td>
      <td><button id="btn7" class="calcBtn calcNum">9</button></td>
      <td><button id="btnMul" class="calcBtn calcOp tr2">x</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button id="btn4" class="calcBtn calcNum">4</button></td>
      <td><button id="btn5" class="calcBtn calcNum">5</button></td>
      <td><button id="btn6" class="calcBtn calcNum">6</button></td>
      <td><button id="btnSub" class="calcBtn calcOp tr2">-</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button id="btn1" class="calcBtn calcNum">1</button></td>
      <td><button id="btn2" class="calcBtn calcNum">2</button></td>
      <td><button id="btn3" class="calcBtn calcNum">3</button></td>
      <td><button id="btnAdd" class="calcBtn calcOp tr2">+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><button id="btn0" class="calcBtn calcNum">0</button></td>
      <td><button id="btnDec" class="calcBtn">.</button></td>
      <td><button id="btnEq" class="calcBtn calcOp tr2">=</button></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>

</section>
```

Should solve your problem.

Comment: I see. I just tried adding the displayValElement to show the new calculation of displayVal but it still shows the 0. Any idea what the second number is being read as? We're storing the first number as pendingVal and resetting displayVal for the second number. The fact its reacting differently makes me think it is being read as something else.

Comment: also, if you add your code inside each case, it does work to get rid of the 0 for the second number but now returns an empty string at first.

Comment: I updated my answer with a workaround that could work.